# grpc: failed to unmarshal the received message proto: bad wiretype

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I'm a little surprised to see this error! The proto object is valid - I've verified it here - https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - `0a06616e6b697461` is the hex dump of my proto object and yet I see this error:

`grpc: failed to unmarshal the received message proto: bad wiretype`

There's no other logs/exceptions printed so I don't know where else to look/what more to look at. I'm relatively new to gRPC/protocol buffers

Comment: It isn't enough for the message to be valid protobuf; it also needs to *match the defined schema* - meaning: if a field is defined as a string, and it receives a varint or fixed32 from  the payload: it is a bad wire type (and so on - that's just a single example); so: do you have the schema that goes with this payload?

Comment: I do, yes! 
```message GetResponse {
  string value = 1;
}```

I'm sending back a `string`, the expected response for this method(`/Get`) is a `string` !

Comment: agreed, that should work; so: without an end-to-end example/repro (in particular: code): it is very hard to comment on this